# Update PhoneGap plugins via Cordova CLI

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, command-line-interface

Is there a simply way to update all Cordova/PhoneGap installed plugins via the command line? Obviously you can remove each one and re-install but I would hope there is something simpler. I've tested out different commands and have tried to find documentation on this with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Shell script / batch file is how I do it:

```
$ vi updateProjectPlugins.shl

#!/bin/sh
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.plugin1
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.plugin2
...
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.plugin1
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.plugin2

$ sh ./updateProjectPlugins.shl
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there is a command for that, but you could write a makefile for that perhaps?